# How to connect lines in Flash CS4 to fill?

Tags: flash, flex

I drew a shape with the pen tool in Flash CS4. When I double click on the line it highlights the entire shape, but I can't fill for some reason.

If I single click, only part of the line is highlighted (before it changes angle). How can I get this line to connect as a shape to invoke fill on it?

Comment: make sure your shape is closed(using the Subselection Tool(A) might help). Also play with the Gap Size options of the Fill Tool, you might get away with 'Close Large Gaps'

Answer (score 2):

Try using the paint bucket to fill your shape (clicking inside of the shape with the paint bucket)

Answer (score 1):

Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and then try the paint bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I created a closed image with line tool.  Then I right clicked on what I created, then selected the  'Flatten Selection'.  Then try your fill tools etc.